# View, Indexed view and join query. What is better performance-wise for multiple joins?

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have a case of multiple joins for multiple tables with various where clauses.

A simple view will always run the select statement (that is what is saved in the database in any case), so filtering the data afterwards seems like a big waste of time.

An indexed view would do the same but would also speed things up by using indexes. At MSDN we also read that ***When a unique clustered index is created on a view, the result set is stored in the database just like a table***

Multiple joins would bring the correct data via the where clause of the query without the need to bring everything at first and filter it later (simple views), nor the need to maintain indexes for the indexed views on somewhat frequently changing data, but would result in more complicated queries.

These joins involve up to 20 tables (some outer (2 to 4) joins that would need to be written either way as the indexed views don't support thems) and the result rows are several thousand (about 2 to 4 million rows in each view).

This is more of a design question, but what would the most efficient (perfomrance-wise and storage wise) in this case?

P.S. The queries are pretty tiresome to write each time in the front-end enviroment development that is why I am looking for another soloution.

Comment: "*A simple view will always run the select statement (that is what is saved in the database in any case)*" No, this is not how Views work.  A view by itself does not *do* anything, nor does it store any data.  A View is simply an alias for a SQL query.  It can only be used in other queries that reference it.  When this happens, the query compiler then optimizes it along with all other parts of the query, including any `WHERE` clauses or other constraints.  As often as not, this will cause the outer explicit `WHERE` clauses to be applied *before* the view results are added to anything else.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that. I thought it worked as an alias for a nested query. So it is no problem in terms of efficiency to use a simple view. But is the indexed view even better?

Answer (score 1):

A few tips for optimizing query performance.

Number 1: Use filters where you can, the optimizer will use those filters to limit the data it returns (Have a 100,000,000 row table, filters actually speed up the viewing process).

Number 2: Implicit conversions: An implicit conversion is where you do not see the conversion from one datatype to another happen, but behind the scenes they chew up a lot of time. 6,000,000 row table from a remote server. 2 min query time with implicit conversion, 5 secs after the implicit conversion removed (BTW datetime <> smalldatetime).

Number 3: use the execution plan, that will let you know where your biggest CPU intensive operations are at (That's how I located the Datetime -> Smalldatetime implicit conversion).